# What exactly means the collation 'de-DE-u-kn-true'

Tags: sql, postgresql, collation

In order to sort a PostgreSQL 14 varchar column with numerical values, I'm using a collation created by

```
CREATE COLLATION de_pos (LOCALE = 'de-DE-u-kn-true', PROVIDER = 'icu');`
```

With such a collation ORDER BY results in correct order like this
1.2.10
1.2.20
1.2.100

Without that special collation ORDER BY results in
1.2.10
1.2.100
1.2.20

I want to know, what every part of that collation definition exactly means ?

de-DE => locale for german-germany
u => UTF8 ????
kn => ????
true => ????

Comment: As a side note: You can also sort version numbers in a different way: `order by string_to_array(the_column, '.')::int[]` but that only works if the values are strictly numeric

Comment: Yes, I know that function and made a test: it works only for two levels (that means for a single dot, 1.10, 1.20, 1.100 etc) but I need an quasi recursive string_to_array due to my values are 1.2.3.10, 1.2.3.20 etc.

Comment: That will work with something like `1.2.3.20` just as well https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1ad50af85706d3afedeaff8b469930c7

Comment: wow, thought I've tested that, great ... thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [ICU Collations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/collation.html#id-1.6.11.4.5.6.5) in the PostgreSQL documentation. This links to the ICU documentation, which - with some indirection - leads to [Unicode Locale Identifier](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35.html#Unicode_locale_identifier), which makes clear that the `-u` introduces the Unicode Locale Extensions, and `kn` is one of those extensions. When you look at [Collation Settings](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Collation_Settings), you'll find `kn` configures numeric ordering. The `true` is the configuration of that option (meaning, numeric ordering is on):

> If set to **on**, any sequence of Decimal Digits (General_Category =
> Nd in the [UAX44]) is sorted at a primary level with its numeric
> value. For example, "A-21" < "A-123". The computed primary weights are
> all at the start of the **digit** reordering group. Thus with an
> untailored UCA table, "a$" < "a0" < "a2" < "a12" < "a⓪" < "aa".

This is sometimes called “natural sort order”.

In other words, `de-DE-u-kn-true` is:

- `de`: language German
- `DE`: region Germany
- `u`: what follows are Unicode Locale Extension
- `kn`: Unicode Locale Extension numeric ordering
- `true`: value of `kn`, meaning numeric ordering is on

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm already stumbled upon the unicode documentation you mentioned. But I didn't find any single occurrence of 'kn' withih the whole document. That's why I'm asking for.

Comment: @Dominik It's listed in the table at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Collation_Settings

Comment: Thank you, I've create a request for extend the PostgreSQL docs with this link.

Comment: @Dominik, was it added to PostgreSQL docs ? What the request URL you created ?

Comment: as of right now [pg docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/collation.html#id-1.6.11.4.5.6.5) include the link in ref to "Unicode Technical Standard #35"

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your collation's sorting behavior by specifying attribute names.
In this case, kn-true stands for natural sorting order or numeric sort order that sorts numbers based on their numeric value.